# Cant really understand that function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I really can't understand this function which uses `Array.from`. I refer the [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) but it doesn't really says much about arguments so can anyone plz explain how's that working.

```
const chunk = (arr, size) => Array.from({length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size)}, (v, i) => arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size));
```

Comment: What your desired result? what you want to achieve with this function ?

Comment: In this section the docs at mdn explain it 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Using_arrow_functions_and_Array.from

Comment: Is "*`Array.from(obj, mapFn)` has the same result as `Array.from(obj).map(mapFn)`, except that it does not create an intermediate array.*" not clear enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It chops up an array into chunks of size `size`, and then sticks them into an array.

The arguments for `Array.from` are the array-like object and a transform function.

The transform function is doing the chunking.

The crucial thing is that a new array is first created with the calculated length similar to:

```
const array = [];
array.length = Math.ceil(arr.length / size);
```

This will create an array with `length` empty slots.

The transform function is then applied to this new array while also referring to `arr`.

Thus `arr` is used to populate the new array.

```js
const chunk = (arr, size) => 
    Array.from({ length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) }, 
        (v, i) => arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size));
console.log(chunk([1, 2, 3], 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

It will break your array into groups of provided `size`.

Array.from will create an array based on what you give him. If you use the method like it's used in the function it will create an array with the provided number of elements.

Please run in your console:

```
Array.from({ length: 3 })
```

It will give you an array with three elements.

The second parameter of Array.from works as an Array.map. You will apply a function to every element of the array.

`v` stands for the element and `i` the index of the element.

So your map function will chunk the provided array into groups :)

```
const chunk = (arr, size) => 
{
    return Array.from(
        {
            length: Math.ceil(arr.length / size) // Length of the array to be created
        }, 

        (v, i) => arr.slice(i * size, i * size + size) //separate the groups
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.from creates a new array from another array which you feed to it. The above function seems to be creating a length attribute from a Math.ceil function and its second argument is slicing up the array from two points, "i * size" is the start point and "i * size + size" is the end point.

These arguments are used like a map function. The first argument, the length, is being manipulated by the second argument, the arrow function, to create a desired output. The link here provides good detail on it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code from which you can understand the `Array.from` function.

```
Array.from({ length: 5 }, function(val, idx){
   return idx
});
```

This will create an array of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`